# Creating Time-Series with days period in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have trouble when using ts() function. How can I create a time-series with days period? Can you examine to me? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be more specific? Give us some details about what you want to do and where you are stuck. Don't worry if it's wrong, we are here for that. Also, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ts(ts_data, frequency = 365)` for daily data with annual seasonality and `ts(ts_data, frequency = 7)` for daily data with weekly seasonality. If there is no seasonality, if your data is from daily, only `ts(ts_data)` will be enough.

Set frequency 1 for year, 4 for quarterly, 12 for monthly and 52 for weekly.